# How to remove or disallow specific characters or symbols using javascript in a textbox

Tags: javascript

How to remove or disallow specific characters or symbols using javascript in a textbox.

For example, when the user inputs: **My name; [ is ] 'alex' & my last name _ is = 'smith'**

I want to remove those uneccesary characters: [] ' = ; _

the result would be like this: 
**My name is alex & my last name is smith**

Comment: No need to try and "cheat" by adding a bunch of unrelated tags.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "My name; [ is ] 'alex' & my last name _ is = 'smith'".replace(/[\[\]=_'';]/g,"") - run in any browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `keyup` event listener and a regexp replacement

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see a working demo

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#some-input");
    
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z& ]/g, "");
});
```

```html
<input id="some-input">
```

The RegExp used is `/[^a-zA-Z& ]/g` which will replace all characters that **don't** match:

- `a-z` lowercase
- `A-Z` uppercase
- `&` symbol
- space

Comment: does it replace these special characters [] ' = ; _

Comment: Yes. I added regexp explanation that should help. Also, run the demo to see it for yourself.

Comment: its only alphabet, I want to allow also other special characters & numbers

Comment: Well add those to the regexp then. Where you see `&`, you can add other allowed characters between the `[...]`.

Comment: @AlexNewbie Then why don't you ask that in the question

Comment: sorry, I forgot about it. @UmaLakshmiKanth

Comment: The only thing I, as a user, would find annoying about this is that it also prevents the arrow keys and Ctrl button from being pressed. So if I want to select all text I can't do it by pressing Ctrl-A or if I want to move the cursor position with they keyboard I can't.

Comment: Maybe in this case it would be better to blacklist characters instead of whitelist.

Comment: @Mike, it's a pretty bad question from the onset. I'm not really putting more effort into it. But if you have a better solution, by all means, please post it ^.^

Comment: @naomik Yeah, I hear you. The question was pretty bad.